# MariaDb Json Support

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, mariadb, alembic

Am using windows 10,

I am running MariaDB 10.1.18 and it says JSON was supported from 10.0.1

but when am trying to do flask db migrations it's throwing error ? json not support.

Comment: "**it** says JSON was supported from 10.0.1" -- what is "it"? Where did you find this information? What exactly you mean by supporting JSON? What SQL are you trying to execute, which error are you getting?

Comment: I want to create a column with json datatype in mariadb. for that am using sqlalchemy and flask migrate to create a table.

Comment: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/data-types/ , i haven't found json data type in the list. i think no support. :(

Comment: MariaDB does not support JSON **type**, it is still in the works. MariaDB 10.2 supports [JSON *functions*](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/json-functions). I am not sure what exactly made you think 10.0 supports JSON -- there are other pieces of functionality related to JSON, e.g. [CONNECT JSON table type](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/connect-json-table-type) or [EXPLAIN / ANALYZE FORMAT=JSON](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/analyze-and-explain-statements), maybe you thought about those.

Comment: Yup, you are right, thank you, I misunderstand as you said

Answer (score 2):

MariaDB as of **10.2** does not yet support JSON type, it is still [in the works](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-9144). MariaDB 10.2 supports [JSON *functions*](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/json-functions).

There is also other JSON-related functionality, e.g. [CONNECT JSON table type](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/connect-json-table-type), or [EXPLAIN / ANALYZE FORMAT=JSON](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/analyze-and-explain-statements).